# Install cocoa pods into new custom iOS workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, workspace

I have an existing framework I want to share between 2 existing related ios Apps. Ive read about workspaces and it appears that a workspace containing both apps and the framework is the recommended way to structure the development environment. Each of the 2 apps are currently in their own workspaces created when I installed cocoa pods in each of those apps. Both apps ultimately need to use the same set of cocoa pods.

Ive created now a new blank workspace to create the structure above. Ive dragged in the .xcodeproj files of the 2 apps and the framework to the new workspace. Now I'm trying to install cocoa pods for this new custom workspace as a whole by navigating in terminal to the new workspace folder and calling pod init but I'm getting the error  No Xcode project found, please specify one.

How can I get cocoa pods to "see" the xcodeproj references of the dragged in projects and framework?